# Spring boot jackson inheritance polymorphism with child class that has same parameters - how to tell jackson what class to use

Tags: java, json, jackson, type-deduction

I have an parent class `EdgeEntity` and a child class `MigrationEdgeEntity extends EdgeEntity`.

Child does not have any new parameters. It's used for migration when some logic is altered/different then in the normal use of `EdgeEntity`.

`MigrationEdgeEntity` in the end saved as `EdgeEntity` in the database.

I can use jackson annotations to make the API endpoint for migration to work. But then when I try to get `EdgeEntitys` from the database it fails. If I don't use the annotations the API migration end point fails.

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION, defaultImpl = EdgeEntity.class)
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MigrationEdgeEntity.class, name = "migrationEdgeEntity")})
```

for EdgeEntity

And for MigrationEdgeEntity I have:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION, property = "type")
@JsonTypeName("migrationEdgeEntity")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
```

I don't understand much about jackson. So those might be the problem but somehow they work for the API

Not sure what to try next.

I am trying to migrate an `EdgeEntity` to a system but there needs to be inherited and overloaded behavior. Kinda much of that actually.

Comment: Thank you for the formatting! Will use it from now on.